Movie about good & evil forces ending in a deity fight
Background of the movie is that it's about a convict I think who's evil & gets possessed by a demon or evil spirit & later the good character also becomes possessed by angel thing.
I remeber this movie which was rented out in 
the uk between 1990-2010 on VHS.I don't remeber a lot except the ending where two forces god vs evil battle it out in the form of possessed people. One being a demon another an angel type thing. When they face off at the end the guy possessed by a demon becomes a whole ball of bodies which grow into a demon/devil entity to attack the good person who also changes from a human possessed by an angel deity creature. 
It isn't Dogma either I'm afraid, I remember very little of the movie,  I remember the evil guy gets possessed at the start of the movie and is hiding out in a abandoned house that's like a pit or something inside. The good character is a normal guy maybe a cop of reporter hunting down a story or case, and when the find the killer near the end the good character gets possessed after the bad guy is about the kill the good guy. 
Very similar to the movie Fallen although it is not. May have starred Jeff goldblum or a similar looking actor. 
Not: Dogma, End Of Days, The prophercy, Constantine, Demons & Angels, Demons,

I suggest you check the guidelines for formulate questions about movie identificatons. it will improve your question.

Marked it as a duplicate as I'm pretty sure you're looking for Hideaway from 1995. If it's not the right film, please let me know.

There's often no need for the OP to do anything with duplicates, they just stay dulpicates. But if you wish to remove the question, there's supposed to be a 'delete' button under it.

Thanks again for the help Walt, think that's all the movies I was trying to remember but will return if more.

What you're describing with your first sentence sounds exactly like the movie Fallen (1998), starring Denzel Washington. In it, Washington plays a cop hunting the demon of a convicted (and executed) murderer. 
Fallen doesn't have a good/evil forces battle or a "ball of bodies" demon at the end, though.

Thanks for the suggestion but it's not fallen I'm afraid similar but no nor is it dogma.
